# What are the reasons why neither C++ nor STL includes multidimensional arrays?

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I understand their lack in C: one can mimic multidimensional arrays as arrays of arrays with no overhead. However, in C++ containers such as `vector` are not well suited for that. Although one can, and (alas) usually does something like `vector< vector< double > >`, such constructions may lead to:

(1) Maintenance problem, such as lack of a guarantee that all inner `vector`s have the same size;

(2) Significant memory overhead, such as multiple instances of inner vector size and data pointer;

(3) Significant performance drawbacks, due to lack of spacial alignment between rows and necessity to do one more indirect memory access per row than necessary.

Why make every developer reinvent the wheel by coding his own `grid` or `matrix`?

Comment: Because you haven't written up the proposal, submitted it to the committee, and argued for its inclusion in the standard.

Comment: [boost](http://boost.org/) might have some alternative. And numerical computations often need special cases (symmetric or triangular or sparse matrixes)

Comment: @CrazyEddie, I cannot possibly be in the 1st 1000 of developers who needed multidimensional arrays. There must have been proposals for that, no?

Comment: As Crazy Eddie said, no proposal seems to have made its way to the standard, yet. These are two of the most promising proposals that I know of: [n4512](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4512.html) and [p0009r0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0009r0.html)

Comment: So use `std::array`. No sense in complaining about a tool being deficient when you're choosing the wrong tool.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I have a few alternatives at my disposal, one from [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html) and another one developed internally. I wonder why we **have to** develop such things over and over again rather than using an stl grid blessed into compatibility by the standard...

Comment: @Michael: A library isn't perfect, when you cannot possibly add anything more to it. A library is perfect, if you cannot take anything away, without impairing its functionality.

Comment: Just because it isn't in the standard library doesn't mean you have to write your own. There are plenty of implementations out there.

Comment: There's many different ways you could implement this.. row major ? column major? how does it grow? should it return delayed-evaluation expressions like Eigen's?  Which functions should be `constexpr` ? Standardizing one will just mean people use it in their homework but keep rolling their own for any real world application.  Not that it is difficult to roll your own.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's rarely used (and I'm certainly not recommending it) the standard does actually include some direct support for using things that at least act like multi-dimensional arrays.

One problem here is that the support that's included works only with `std::valarray`, not `std::vector`. Another problem is that most documentation of the capability is rather poor, so it's often difficult to even understand that what's being provided really is a multi-dimensional array capability. Yet another problem is that using `vallarray` (and almost everything associated) tends to be a bit on the clumsy side at best--every once in a while you run into odd limitations that indicate that it was never really finished.

Nonetheless, yes, `std::slice` and `std::gslice` provide the ability to (for example) address a column of a, say, 3D array.

Answer (score 1):

Because the programmers usually don't actually need them so desperately. If everything I want is a two-dimensional (or N-dimensional) matrix with equally sized rows, every time I just used one dimensional array covering the entire matrix (and as a bonus it is also better for memory locality). Sure, it then requires calculating the indices manually, but that calculation is pretty simple (`matrix[r*row_size+c]`). Even padding can be done easily if necessary.

And yes, for something more fancy there are already some implementations available in Boost.

One of the few cases where I would really need a true multi-dimensional array would be if the "rows" wouldn't be of equal size.